# bounds for parameters in mle2() with optimizer=optimx

Tags: r, mle

In the `mle2`, I used "optimx" as a optimizer. I want to use lower and upper bounds for parameters. How can I do this?

For example:

```
 library("bbmle"); library("optimx")
 y <- c(0.654, 0.613, 0.315, 0.449, 0.297, 0.402, 0.379,
        0.423, 0.379, 0.3235, 0.269, 0.740, 0.418, 0.412, 
        0.494, 0.416, 0.338, 0.392, 0.484, 0.265) 
 gamma4 <- function(shape, scale) {
  -sum(dgamma(y, shape = shape, scale = scale,log = TRUE))
 } 
 gm <- mean(y) 
 cv <- var(y)/mean(y) 
 m5 <- mle2(gamma4,start = list(shape = gm/cv, scale = cv),
            optimizer="optimx") 
 m5
```

Or:

```
  mle2(gengamma3,start = list(shape = ci, 
      scale = bet, k=alp),
      optimizer="optimx")
```

Thanks

Comment: which method are you using within `optimx` ?

Comment: I didn't write any method, is it wrong? What should I do?

Comment: well, what does your output look like?  Can you give us a [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) please ?

Comment: For example my data:                                                                                          y=c(0.654, 0.613, 0.315, 0.449, 0.297, 0.402, 0.379, 0.423, 0.379, 0.3235,
0.269, 0.740, 0.418, 0.412, 0.494, 0.416, 0.338, 0.392, 0.484, 0.265)   To obtain mles of gamma distribution:   
 gamma4 = function(shape, scale) {
 -sum(dgamma(y, shape = shape, scale = scale,log = TRUE))
}

gm = mean(y)
cv = var(y)/mean(y)
m5 = mle2(gamma4,start = list(shape = gm/cv, scale = cv),optimizer="optimx")
m5

Comment: My output:                                                                                                  mle2(minuslogl = gamma4, start = list(shape = gm/cv, scale = cv), 
    optimizer = "optimx")

Coefficients:
      shape       scale 
11.40723825  0.03709274 

Log-likelihood: 15.18

Comment: then @Hamsternik's answer looks fine to me.

Comment: So, If I don't use bounds, can I use "optimx" without method?

Comment: in any case there's a default method.  But if you're not specifying any particular method, then you're just getting some of the same optimizers that are built into `optim()` (Nelder-Mead by default, or L-BFGS-B if you specify bounds), so I don't really see the advantage of using `optimx` here ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write lower function as last parametr, like in example below:

```
## use bounded optimization
## the lower bounds are really > 0, but we use >=0 to stress-test
## profiling; note lower must be named
(fit1 <- mle2(LL, method="L-BFGS-B", lower=c(ymax=0, xhalf=0)))
p1 <- profile(fit1)
```

Or in that one:

```
# try bounded optimization with nlminb and constrOptim
(fit1B <- mle2(LL, optimizer="nlminb", lower=c(lymax=1e-7, lhalf=1e-7)))
p1B <- profile(fit1B)
confint(p1B)
(fit1C <- mle2(LL, optimizer="constrOptim", ui = c(lymax=1,lhalf=1), ci=2,
   method="Nelder-Mead"))
```

But for fully understanding i advise to look [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/bbmle/docs/mle2)